# How do I "edit" Chromium browser?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I am wanting to get the source code for Chromium so that I could edit the browser and see what I could make of it. On the Chromium website I cannot find any 'download link' for the source code, and I cannot find any answers. How do I find the source code for Chromium and edit it?

Comment: Maybe you missed this https://www.chromium.org/developers there is `start here` links check them.

Comment: @BladeMight that documentation is bit outdated, do you have any other link that newbies can follow?